# tex4ht: Single quote will trigger `Double superscript` error in `align` environments

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
Now aligned
\begin{align*}
  i_\lambda'^* &= a\\
               &= b
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Compile with `tex4ebook`, the error message `htlatex: ./test.tex    8    Double superscript.` pops up. So far I have only found this issue under `align` environments. For example, there is no error for `$i_\lambda'^*$`. I look for workarounds for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'^*` works in latex due to some low level trick parsing code inherited from plain tex.

htlatex like several other packages needs `^` to work like a normal macro argument.

The construct expands to `^{\prime*}` and using that form works with htlatex.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
Now aligned
\begin{align*}
  i_\lambda^{\prime*} &= a\\
               &= b
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Probably tex4ht could be extended to support your original form if you were to put in a feature request.